# Square integrable martingale bounded in $L^2$ if and only if the sum difference is square integrable

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $\{Y_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ be a martingale with $ \mathbb{E}[Y_n^2] < \infty $ for all $n$. Show that
$$
        \sup_{n \ge 0} \mathbb{E}[Y_n^2] < \infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n \ge 0} \mathbb{E} [(Y_{n + 1} - Y_n)^2] < \infty. 
$$

**My attempt**: I think I was able to solve it for "$\Rightarrow$": For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$
(Y_n)^2 = (Y_0 + (Y_1 - Y_0) + ... + (Y_n - Y_{n - 1}))^2
$$
Then setting $D_m = Y_m - Y_{m - 1}$, we get

$$
(Y_n)^2 = Y_0^2 + \sum_{m = 1}^n D_m^2 + 2 \sum_{1 \le r < m \le n} D_rD_m
$$
and taking the expected value

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y_n^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2_0] + \sum_m \mathbb{E}[D_m^2] + 2 \sum_{r < m} \mathbb{E}[D_rD_m].
$$

For $1 \le r \le m$, 
$$
\mathbb{E}[D_rD_m] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(D_rD_m | \mathcal{F}_{r - 1})] = \mathbb{E}[D_m \mathbb{E}(D_r | \mathcal{F}_{r - 1})] = 0,
$$

since $D_m$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{r - 1}$ and

$$
\mathbb{E}(D_r|\mathcal{F}_{r - 1}) = 0.
$$
Since $\{Y_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ is bounded in $L^2$, i.e. $\sup_{n} \mathbb{E}[Y_n^2] < \infty$, we have that $\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[D_m^2]$ converges.

Is this correct reasoning? Also I am not sure how to solve the statement assuming "$\Leftarrow$" condition. Are there some hints or ideas I can use to solve it?

Comment: Your reasoning that $\mathbb{E}(D_r D_m)=0$ is wrong. Firstly, you need to assume $r \neq m$, and, secondly, $D_m$ need not be independent of $\mathcal{F}_{r-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct reasoning would have been: 
For $1 \le r < m$, 
$$
\mathbb{E}[D_rD_m] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(D_rD_m | \mathcal{F}_r)] = \mathbb{E}[D_r \mathbb{E}(D_m | \mathcal{F}_r)] = 0,
$$

since $D_r$ is $\mathcal{F}_r$-measurable and

$$
\mathbb{E}(D_m|\mathcal{F}_r) = 0.
$$
Thus, $$
\mathbb{E}[Y_n^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2_0] + \sum_{m=1}^n \mathbb{E}[D_m^2],
$$ this being bounded iff $$\sum_{m=1}^ \infty{E}[D_m^2]<\infty.$$
So you were very close to the solution, indeed.